# jQuery Isotope - Ajax Page Load and Initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-isotope, window-load

I have a page which can be reloaded (no problem) and can be called via an `Ajax` call.

When I put the initialization code for the `isotope` plugin in `$(document).ready` then my isotope items are all messed up. In `$(window).load` everything works fine.

The problem is that when calling the page via `Ajax` the `load` event is obviously not firing.

When I put the initialization in the `Ajax` callback I have the same problem as in the `$(document).ready`.

My current workaround is a `setTimeout` in my `$(document).ready`. This is for obvious reasons not a good solution.

Any nice solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking to see if the ajax has successfully loaded and then call isotope.

```
$.getScript("ajax.html", function(data,exception) {   
    if(exception === "success")
    {
        masonryBlocks();
    }
});

function masonryBlocks(){
  $(function(){    
      var $container = $('#container');

      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        masonry: {
          columnWidth: 1
        }
      });
  });
}
```